# Match word beginning with known pattern

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am struggling to match a whole word which starts with a known pattern and ends either with a white space or with the end of the string. I think I have the pattern for the word:

```
pat <- "https?:\\/\\/.*"

require(stringr)
str_extract("http://t.co/som7hing", pat)
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing" # So far so good...
```

what I don't get is how to define the boundaries of the word. There are four possible situations to consider:

1. My URL is at the beginning of the string
2. My URL is at the end of the string
3. My URL is preceded by some other token
4. My URL is followed by some other token

In all four cases my pattern should only match the URL, from start to end.

```
str_extract("something something http://t.co/som7hing", pat)
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing"
```

So far so good...

```
str_extract("http://t.co/som7hing ", pat)
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing "
```

First problem, a trailing space is also matched

```
str_extract("http://t.co/som7hing #hash name", pat)
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing #hash name"
```

Second problem all trailing words are matched

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is

```
pat <- "https?:\\/\\/\\S*"
```

The `.` in regex will match any character, *including spaces*. What you want is to match any non-whitespace character, which is done using `\S`.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator; causing both problems with trailing whitespace and trailing words being matched. Therefore, `.*` will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match.

I recommend using the following regular expression:

```
re <- '\\bhttps?://\\S+'
```

We use `\b` which is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). A word boundary does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not. `\S` matches any non-white space character.

You can see as we perform this on your posted examples.

```
x  <- c('http://t.co/som7hing', 
        'http://t.co/som7hing ',
        'something something http://t.co/som7hing', 
        'http://t.co/som7hing #hash name',
        'foohttp://www.example.com',
        'barhttp://www.foo.com    ')

re <- '\\bhttps?://\\S+'

for (i in x) print(str_extract(i, re))
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing"
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing"
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing"
# [1] "http://t.co/som7hing"
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
```

The last two were not matched because of the word boundary, now if you want to match the prefix anywhere in a string, remove the boundary from the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick. It matches up to a space, and stops there. I've used backslash to escape the colon and the forward slashes from the addresses. Instead of matching any charater for any number, I've matched any character that's not a space [!\S]

```
https?\:\/\/[!\S]*
```

I've tested this in http://regexpal.com/

Comment: In a character class the character used to make a negation is `^`. However you don't need a negation at all since `\S` means *all character that is not a whitespace character* (in other words `[^\S]` = `\s`)